# PostgreSQL replication and index usage counts

Tags: postgresql, index-statistics

Postgres collects index usage statistics in `pg_catalog.pg_stat_all_indexes`. Does anyone know if those statistics are identical across master and replica nodes when using “physical” wal replication?

Comment: which replication method you are using? If WAL then the index usage statistics should be identical across both the master and replica nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those counts are not transmitted over WAL.  They are part of the "ephemeral" stats system. Surely you noticed they were different between servers, no?